# Problems using curve_fit for multivariate gaussian fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, scientific-computing

I am so stuck trying to fit 3D gaussians, and I am hoping someone can see some silly mistake I am making, because I have spent hours debugging to no avail.

I have a 3d image stored in an array called "data", where data[x, y, z] gives the grayscale intensity at the point (x, y, z). I know that this 3d image follows a 3D Gaussian distribution, with a peak near the center of the image, but I am interested in the amplitude and spread. I am trying to fit this 3d array to a gaussian of the form [image] My function in Python is:

```
def gaussian_3d(X, A, x0, y0, z0, sigx, sigy, sigz, offset):
    x, y, z = X
    return offset + A*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigx**2) - \
            (y-y0)**2/(2*sigy**2) - (z-z0)**2/(2*sigz**2))
```

And the way I am doing this is as follows: if my image is of size 3 x 4 x 5, then I create a meshgrid (0...2) x (0...3) x (0...4), and then try to fit the intensity values to the function above.
My code looks like this:

```
def fit_gauss_3d(data):
    dim = data.shape
    
    # Step 1: set up meshgrid
    x, y, z = np.arange(0, dim[0]), np.arange(0, dim[1]), np.arange(0, dim[2])
    X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
    data_in = np.vstack((X.ravel(),Y.ravel(),Z.ravel()))
    data_out = data.ravel()

    # Step 2: make good guess of the center "peak" point of the gaussian (x0, y0, z0)
    #         by using slices along the middle and finding the position of the maxes
    mid1, mid2, mid3 = dim[0]//2, dim[1]//2, dim[2]//2
    x0, y0, z0 = np.argmax(data[:, mid2, mid3]), np.argmax(data[mid1, :, mid3]), np.argmax(data[mid1, mid2, :])

    # Step 3: Set lower/upper bounds for parameter search
    delta = 0.5  # I am saying that the fit peak must be within +/- 0.5 of the initial guess
    p0 = (data_max + 0.05, x0, y0, z0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.05)
    #         Note: I know that sigmas are between 0.7 and 2.5, and offset is between 0 and 5
    lower_bound = [data_max * 0.9, x0 - delta, y0 - delta, z0 - delta, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0]
    upper_bound = [data_max*1.1 + 0.1, x0 + delta, y0 + delta, z0 + delta, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5]

    # Step 4: Fit
    p_param, p_cov = opt.curve_fit(gauss_3d, data_in, data_out, p0=p0, maxfev=50000, bounds=(lower_bound, upper_bound))

    return p_param


def predict_gauss_3d(params, dims):
    x = np.arange(0, dims[0])
    y = np.arange(0, dims[1])
    z = np.arange(0, dims[2])
    XX, YY, ZZ = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
    X = np.vstack((XX.ravel(),YY.ravel(),ZZ.ravel()))
    return gaussian_3d(X, *params).reshape(dims)

def plot_results(orig, sec):
    ''' Plot original and second fitted image'''
    mid1, mid2, mid3 = dim[0]//2, dim[1]//2, dim[2]//2

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
    ax1.plot(orig[:, mid2, mid3], label='orig')
    ax1.plot(sec[:, mid2, mid3], label='fitted')
    ax1.legend(loc="upper left")

    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 2)
    ax2.plot(orig[mid1, :, mid3], label='orig')
    ax2.plot(sec[mid1, :, mid3], label='fitted')
    ax2.legend(loc="upper left")

    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 3)
    ax3.plot(orig[mid1, mid2], label='orig')
    ax3.plot(sec[mid1, mid2], label='fitted')
    ax3.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I plotted the projection of the fits along the middle axes. The first pic is varying x and keeping y, z at their midpoints, the second is varying y and keeping x, z at their midpoints, and so forth.
Some of my fits are reasonable, something like this:
[image]
While most are insanely bad, and not even Gaussian looking! For the below image, it chose the following parameters: [image]. Clearly, I am either plotting wrong or fitting wrong. Can someone help me out? Is my meshgridding messed up somehow?
[image]

Comment: For a start: `sigx` is not `sig_x` and `amplit` is not defined in your function. Please post the code you actually use.

Comment: Sorry @Mr.T, I have made that correction. I changed the variable names (amplit became A, sig_x became sigx) to make them shorter and make it more compact on stackoverflow but there is no difference in the actual function, it is just variable names. I had to remove a lot of commented lines and make things more readable for stackoverflow, as I am still trying to debug and trying different things to try and fix it. I have a strong feeling there is something wrong with the meshgridding, because I don't know how the second graph in the last image could look like an inverted gaussian.